# Flagging users as spam and giving a reason for doing so

Tags: 7, users, flags, advertising

I am creating a community site using Drupal7. The users of my site should be able to report other users as *spam users*. For this I am using the Flag module. I have created a flag called *Report User for Abuse*, and placed it on the user profile so that other users may report the user by clicking on the flag.

**I want that the flagging user should give a small summary for the reason he or she is reporting the other user as spam etc.**

Once this was done, I created a view for the site admin which shows him/her all the *reported users*. The admin may then see the reason, verify it and take appropriate actions.
Am I going in the right way about this or is there any other way as well?

Comment: I looked into this thread http://drupal.org/node/871064 but it doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 6):

Why not use the [Flag Note](http://drupal.org/project/flag_note) module.

> Extends the Flag Module to allow users to enter a note when they flag
>   a piece of content and eventually build a flag history.
>
> Usage examples:
>
> - flag nodes or comments for abuse providing a descriptive reason
> - flag users as friends leaving a hint
>
> It's possible to opt to keep old notes even when the content gets
>   unflagged

Answer (score 1):

Try this module [Flagging Form](http://drupal.org/project/flagging_form). It says

> you could now attach fields to Flags, this module, Flag forms,
>   provides a form for filling out these fields.